# Sorting a vector of strings by the first letter in non-ascii order in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, ascii, bubble-sort

I have a text file with a list of words.

I used `ifstream` to read these words into a `vector` and now I am trying to sort them in an order similar to:

```
A a B b C c [...]
```

I tried to implement this using a third for loop inside of a bubble search algorithm to look at the first character of each word (I know this is far from the most efficient way especially if I was using a large data set)

And then check whether the letter and the next letter were uppercase or lowercase and switching if the uppercase letter was the same letter as the current letter, but this didn't seem to work.

```
void bubble_Sort (vector <string> & words)
{
  for (unsigned i = words.size(); i >= 2; --i)
  {
    for (unsigned k = 0; k + 1 < i; k++)
    {
      int hi = k+1;
      string temp1 = words[hi];
      string temp2 = words[k];
      int smallsize = words[hi].size();
      int smallprecedence = 0;

      if (words[k].size() < words[hi].size())
        smallsize = words[k].size();

      for (unsigned j = 0; j < smallsize; j++)
      {
        if (temp1[j] >= 'A' && temp1[j] <= 'Z')
        {
          if (temp2[j] >='a' && temp2[j] <= 'z')
          {
            char lowercase1 = temp1[j] + 32;
            if (lowercase1 == temp2[j])
            {
              string temp = words[k];
              words[k] = words[hi];
              words[hi] = temp;
              break;
            }
          }

          else if (temp2[j] >= 'A' && temp2[j] <= 'Z')
          {
            if (temp1[j] < temp2[j])
            {
              string temp = words[k];
              words[k] = words[hi];
              words[hi] = temp;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        if (temp1[j] >= 'a' && temp1[j] <= 'z')
        {
          if (temp2[j] >= 'A' && temp2[j] <= 'Z')
          {
            char uppercase1 = temp1[j] - 32;
            if (uppercase1 < temp2[j])
            {
              string temp = words[k];
              words[k] = words[hi];
              words[hi] = temp;
              break;
            }
          }

          else if (temp2[j] >= 'a' && temp2[j] <= 'z')
          {
            if (temp1[j] < temp2[j])
            {
              string temp = words[k];
              words[k] = words[hi];
              words[hi] = temp;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        else if (temp1[j] == temp2[j] && temp1.size() < temp2.size())
          ++smallprecedence;
      }

      if (smallprecedence == smallsize)
      {
        string temporary = words[k];
        words[k] = words[hi];
        words[hi] = temporary;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing your own bubblesort as an exercise? If not, you should just use `std::sort` and implement the comparison function.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to use bubble sort to sort the vector in the order A a B b and so on even though in ascii a is bigger than B, which is the problem I've been having.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just modify the default comparison function so aA < bB (regardless of case) and A < a.

EDIT I used the wrong comparison function. It should return `true` for `<`, and `false` for `>=`. This has been fixed

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
//
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{ 
   const char* s1=lhs.c_str();
   const char* s2=rhs.c_str();
   while(true) {
     // first ignore case
     if ( std::toupper(*s1) < std::toupper(*s2) ) return true;
     if ( std::toupper(*s1) > std::toupper(*s2) ) return false;
     // end of both strings, exact match
     if ( *s1 == 0 && *s2 == 0 ) return false;
     // compare upper case vs lower case ('A' vs 'a')
     if ( *s1 > *s2) return false;
     if ( *s1 < *s2) return true;
     ++s1; ++s2;
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the hard-coded ASCII-isms. C and C++ have long had functions for determining whether a character is a letter, a digit, uppercase, lowercase, etc. Look them up.

Second, describe **clearly** what goes into determining the order that you want the result to be in.

Third, from that description, **write a function** that takes two strings, and tells you whether the first string should come before the second. Use **that function** in the sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a vector using `std::sort` and get a reference to the first character in a `std::string` using `std::string::at()` :

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
//
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{ 
    char l_ch, r_ch;
    l_ch = lhs.at(0);
    r_ch = rhs.at(0);
    return l_ch < r_ch;
});
```

Comment: Better check for empty strings before using `at()`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: u r correct, it was just to provide a snippet, code not even tested. std::compare could have been used for the comparision , but OP insists about first letter

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really enough to skip exactly equal prefixes and then compare once with uppercasing:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
//
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{ 
  const char* s1=lhs.c_str();
  const char* s2=rhs.c_str();
  while(*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {++s1; ++s2;}  
  int rc = toupper(*s1) - toupper(*s2);
  if (rc) return rc;
  return *s1 - *s2;
});
```

If you need to compare by first letter only, simply remove `while(*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {++s1; ++s2;}`